# capybara - Clicking a button without an id

Tags: button, click, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to to click the button in this html code

`<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button></div>`

I've already tried find with various combinations, the closest I came to success was with this code:

```
click_on "Kapat"
```

The problem is that there are 3 copies of the same button in the page, so my question is; is there a way to specify this particular div ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the button has a specific path, you could use `within` or a `find` down to that path, but that path to the element would have to be unique in the page or you end up with the same problem (though, I believe using `:xpath` would give you a bit more flexibility here).

```
within ".modal-footer" do
  click_on "Kapat"
end

within ".another-selector" do
  click_on "Kapat"
end
```